# android wizard to collect data

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, material-design

The first time a user runs our App they will need to register and this involves entering and sending data in a number of steps.

I had envisaged this could be done with a user completing each step and pressing "next" and the current window sliding off to the left as the next one slid in from the right.

Is there an established material design guideline for this?
Is there a widget which will do it?

I need to support back to Android 4.1 (API 16)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

take a look to [Android view pager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Great plan. Thanks.